# How to change h3 text from database where the database is on select option

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I'm still learning Laravel, and not understand how to read the Doc. So i just explore and learn by doing. But now i'm stuck.

I have Tables, where :

- Table Hewan (Animal)
- Table Grade (Animal Meat Grade)
- Table Bobot (Weight)

In Table Hewan i have : ***Kambing***, ***Domba***, and ***Sapi***. Every Kambing, Domba, and Sapi have grade, where there's from Table Grade. In Table Grade i have **HMT**, **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, and **E**. In every hewan had their own bobot, where bobot is calcified by grade.

Then in that case i need 3 Pivot tables, where Table KambingGrade, Table KambingBobot, and Table GradeBobot. Here's the code :

```
// TABLE HEWAN
Schema::create('hewan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nama');
            // $table->string('hewan_slug')->unique();
            $table->string('coverimg')->nullable();
            $table->integer('qty');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

// MODEL HEWAN
    protected $table = 'hewan';
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function relationToBobot(){
        return $this -> belongsToMany(Bobot::class, 'hewanbobot');
    }

    public function relationToGrade(){
        return $this -> belongsToMany(Grade::class, 'hewangrade');
    }
```

```
// TABLE GRADE
Schema::create('grade', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('grade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

// MODEL GRADE
    protected $table = 'grade';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function relationToHewan(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Hewan::class, 'hewangrade');
    }

    public function relationToBobot(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bobot::class, 'gradebobot');
    }
```

```
// TABLE BOBOT
Schema::create('bobot', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('bobot');
            $table->integer('harga');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

// MODEL BOBOT
    protected $table = 'bobot';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function relationToHewan(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Hewan::class, 'hewanbobot');
    }

    public function relationToGrade(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Grade::class, 'gradebobot');
    }
```

```
// TABLE HEWANGRADE
Schema::create('hewangrade', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('hewan_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('grade_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('hewan_id')->references('id')->on('hewan')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('grade_id')->references('id')->on('grade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

// TABLE HEWANBOBOT
Schema::create('hewanbobot', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('hewan_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('bobot_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('hewan_id')->references('id')->on('hewan')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('bobot_id')->references('id')->on('bobot')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

// TABLE GRADEBOBOT
Schema::create('gradebobot', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('grade_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('bobot_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('grade_id')->references('id')->on('grade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('bobot_id')->references('id')->on('bobot')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

I Already show Grade and Bobot based on Hewan param routes, this is my Blade View :

```
<span><small>Rp</small>(I DONT KNOW HOW TO SHOW HARGA (PRICE) BASED ON SELECTED BOBOT)</span>
<ul>
    <li class="col-xs-4">
        <label>Pilih Grade</label>
        <div class="quinty">
            <select class="selectpicker" name="grade" id="grade">
                @foreach ($hewangrade as $hewangrades)
                    @foreach ($grade->where('grade', $hewangrades->grade) as $grade1)
                        <option value="{{ $grade1->grade }}">{{ $grade1->grade }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-4">
        <label>Pilih Bobot</label>
        <div class="quinty">
            <select class="selectpicker" name="bobot" id="bobot">
                @foreach ($hewangrade as $hewangrades)
                    @foreach ($grade->where('grade', $hewangrades->grade) as $grade1)
                        @foreach ($hewanbobot as $hewanbobots)
                            @foreach ($bobot->where('bobot', $hewanbobots->bobot) as $bobot1)
                                @foreach ($gb->where('grade_id', $grade1->id)->where('bobot_id', $bobot1->id) as $gradezz)
                                    <option class="{{ $grade1->grade }}">{{ $bobot1->bobot }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my Controller :

```
public function show(Hewan $hewan){
        $nama = $hewan->nama;
        $id = $hewan->id;
        $img = $hewan->coverimg;
        $qty = $hewan->qty;
        $grade = Grade::all();
        $bobot = Bobot::all();
        $gb = GradeBobot::all();
        $hewangrade = $hewan->relationToGrade;
        $hewanbobot = $hewan->relationToBobot;
        return view('hewan', compact('nama','id', 'img', 'qty', 'bobot', 'hewangrade', 'hewanbobot','grade', 'gb'));
}
```

I Already show Grade based on attached HewanGrade, Bobot based on attached HewanBobot and GradeBobot.

So the questions is :

1. How to show Bobot based on selected Grade in the Hewan
2. Any correction for my coding?

Sorry if my program is untidy. Help me brother, i want to learn more and more.

Thanks

My Expectation :

- <span> Showing price based on selected bobot
- Correction for my code for the simplify and minim

#NOTE : I guess it need JQuery, but i'm new learner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+cascading+select+ajax+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.